# Passing value from textbox to actionLink in ASP.net MVC without posting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, html.textboxfor

I need something like on a "Create New" page, a field for search employee. Search results are shown in a modal dialog and on user selection employee field on "Create New" page is filled. I t does not makes sense to hit HTTPPost action for search employee popup.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProjectManager, 
      new { id = "employeeSearchTxt", 
            @class="input-medium search-query" })

@Html.ActionLinkNonEncoded("<i class=\"icon-search\"></i> Search Directory",
 "SearchEmployees", "EmployeeSearch",
 new { query = Model.ProjectManager},
 new { @class = "btn btn-success modal-link" })
```

I could not understand how I should pass the TextBox (current) value not what present in Model.ProjectManager property to ActionLink?

Thanks